# Show Deleted Answers at head for Stack Exchange

Tags: script, moderation

## Description

Script practice.

To view your own deleted answers/questions on a Stack Exchange account, you always need to scroll all the way down to see the "Deleted answers" tag. I've written a script to address this issue. <del>If you, like me, don't want to press the Home/End keys</del>

## How it works

[image]

[image]

## Installation

[GreasyFork backup, Click to install](https://update.greasyfork.org/scripts/475785/Show%20Deleted%20Answers%20at%20head%20for%20StackExchange.user.js)

## Bugs, requests

You can post bugs or requests in [the GreasyFork script feedback](https://greasyfork.org/scripts/475785-show-deleted-answers-at-head-for-stackexchange/feedback) or answer [this question itself](https://stackapps.com/questions/10511/show-deleted-answers-at-head-for-stackexchange).